# Did a static variable is global variable?

Tags: c++, file, pointers, printf, runtime-error

I have two questions in C++.

First, is a global variable the same thing as a static variable? What is particular about a static variable?

Secondly, I actually code a project and if I do not use static variable, my code sent me the next error :

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'szData' was
>   corrupted.

This error appear due to sprintf, because I remove it and all is ok..

```
bool CreateFile(MyCards** ppCards)
{
    fstream ficCar;
    static char szData[31];
    ficEmployes.open("./my_cards.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!ficCar.fail())
    {
        ficCar.close();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        sort(ppCards, ppCards + 26271, OrderedCards); 
        ppCards.open("./nom_cartes.index", ios::out | ios::binary);

        if (ficCar.fail())
        {
            throw "Error";
        }
        else
        {

            for (int indice = 0; indice < 10123; indice++)
            {
                sprintf(szData, "%-20s %010d \n",
                    ppCards[indice]->GetNom(),
                    ppCards[indice]->GetPosition());

                ficCar.write(szEnregistrement, 30);

            }

            ficCar.close();

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: I cant spot any `static` in that code

Comment: if `ficCar` did not fail you close it and return and only if it failed you continue to use it, is that really what you want?

Comment: Oops! I make an error. I edited my code on SO, it's static char szData[31];

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: is `ficCar` vs `ficEmployes` also error by editing here? You actually never open `ficCar` but check its `fail()` twice and close it

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, because I write the content of my pointer and after I close my fstream. If it fail, it's because the file exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static variable does not equal to global, static variable can have scope: within compilation unit, function, class.

For question #2, szData has 31 bytes but `sprintf` try to put more on it, so it corrupt things nearby. Even you make it static, it will corrupt something else.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Calvin! This help me alot! I just add 2 to my array and I had no  more error about memory! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

An object declared at namespace scope is `static`, and that makes it "global" in a sense.

An object declared in a function and marked `static` could sort of be called a "global" due to the way its scope behaves, but it cannot be accessed from outside the function.

For this reason, you'd be better off avoiding the term "global" and sticking with standard C++ terminology that is precise.

As for your code fault, you're trying to put more than 31 characters into an array of 31 characters. That's just not going to go well.